# Finding the centre of the group $GL(n,k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I want to compute the centre of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$

Now I saw a good answer by @1015 on the following proof by @Ben: [The Center of $\operatorname{GL}(n,k)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299626/the-center-of-operatornamegln-k).

Here is the answer: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/299637/381362

I understand that $(I_n+E_{i,j})A=A(I_n+E_{i,j})$ and therefore all the matrices of the form: $(I_n+E_{i,j}) \in Z(GL(n,k))$

Here are the parts where I lack understanding:

- What is the purpose of the equivalence:  $(I_n+E_{i,j})A=A(I_n+E_{i,j})\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad E_{i,j}A=AE_{i,j}$. I understand why that equivalence is true but $E_{i,j} \notin GL(n,k)$ so I don't understand why that piece of information is necessary.
- What does he means by: "Now compute the appropriate coefficients in the latter"?
- How does he know that this represents all the elements of $Z(GL(n,k)$?

Comment: *"I understand that $(I_n+E_{i,j})A=A(I_n+E_{i,j})$ And therefore All the matrices of the form: $(I_n+E_{i,j}) \in Z(GL(n,k))$"*.  This is wrong: $I + E_{ij}$ is **not** generally an element of $Z(GL(n,k))$.  What we can say though is that if $A$ is an element of the center, then it must commute with $I + E_{ij}$, which is what 1015 is actually saying

Comment: Wait If A is an element of the center of $GL(n,k)$ doesn't it commute with every element  of $GL(n,k)$?

Comment: Yes, and $(I + E_{ij})$ is such an element

Comment: So what does $I+E_{i,j}$ tell us about A? (which in its generality is $Z(GL(n,k)$

Comment: It tells us that $A E_{ij} = E_{ij} A$, which tells us something about the entries ("coefficients") of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

In his proof, the answerer starts by establishing that 
$$
A \in Z(GL) \implies A(I + E_{ij}) = (I + E_{ij})A \quad \forall i\neq j
\implies \\
AE_{ij} = E_{ij}A \quad \forall i\neq j
$$
Perhaps it seems strange that we're not "using every element of $Z$", but this will be enough to show that $A$ must be a multiple of the identity, as we show with a "computation of appropriate coefficients".

In particular: note that $AE_{ij} = E_{ij}A$ means that all their entries are equal.  However, the $p,q$ entry of $AE_{ij}$ is given by
$$
[AE_{ij}]_{p,q} = [Ae_ie_j^T]_{p,q} = e_p^T Ae_i e_j^Te_p = 
\delta_{jq} A_{pi}
$$
where $\delta$ is a Konecker delta, and
$$
[E_{ij}A]_{p,q} = [e_ie_j^TA]_{p,q} = e_p^T e_i e_j^TAe_p = 
\delta_{ip} A_{jp}
$$
From there, one must note that these will be equal for all combinations of $i,j,p,q$ only if $A$ is a multiple of the identity.

---

Alternative explanation: $AE_{ij} = (Ae_i)e_j^T$ is a matrix whose $j$th column is occupied by the $i$th column of $A$, and whose other entries are all $0$. $E_{ij}A = e_i(e_j^TA)$ is a matrix whose $i$th row is occupied by the $j$th row of $A$, and whose other entries are all $0$.

These two products must be equal for all $i \neq j$.  This is enough for us to deduce that $A$ is a multiple of the identity.

Comment: You may find my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737592/find-the-center-of-the-group-gln-r-of-invertible-nxn-matrices/737651#737651) helpful