# Regular Matrix A with $A*B=B*A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I need help with an exercise, probably I think too difficult, so it would be nice to have just a beginning:

$A\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, with $A*B=B*A$ for all $B\in GL_n(\mathbb{R}) $. Show that there exists a $r\in \mathbb{R}$ without $0$ with $A=r*E_n$ where $E_n$ is the $n \times n$ unit matrix.

It is obvious that this statement is true but probably I'm too dumb to show it correctly, so it would be great to have a beginning.

Thank you very much, have a nice day and stay healthy!

Comment: take $E_{p,k}=(e_{ij})$ with $e_{ij}=1$ if $(i,j)=(p,k)$ and $e_{ij}=0$ otherwise. now replace $B$ with every  $E_{p,k}$ and see what it gives you.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/737592/81360) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299626/81360).